# JsonMappingException$Reference not found when calling a RESTful web service using JBoss 7 and RESTeasy

Tags: java, json, jackson, jboss7.x, resteasy

I have created a RESTful web service producing JSON content with JAX-RS, it uses some JPA entities, it runs on JBoss 7.1.3.

I get the following error message when calling this web service:

> 13:23:11,834 ERROR
>   [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/*****WebServices].[com.******.******.rest.config.ApplicationConfig]]
>   (http-/127.0.0.1:8080-2) "Servlet.service()" for the servlet
>   com.******.******.rest.config.ApplicationConfig threw an
>   exception: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException$Reference from [Module
>   "org.codehaus.jackson.jackson-mapper-asl:main" from local module
>   loader @6514af16 (roots:
>   C:**********\jboss-as-7.1.3.Final-bundled4STR\modules)]  at
>   org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:190)
>     at
>   org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:468)
>     at
>   org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:456)
>     at
>   org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
>     at
>   org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:120)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:166)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:112)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:446)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:150)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:112)

Before trying [this solution](https://blog.avisi.nl/2013/05/07/jboss-as7-1-and-resteasy-upgrading-jackson/), I replaced modules\org\codehaus\jackson\jackson-mapper-asl\main\jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.2.jar by a more recent version, I tried with the version 1.9.3 and with the version 1.9.7. It didn't help.

I added org.codehaus.jackson.jackson-mapper-asl into jboss-deployment-structure.xml but it didn't solve my problem.

I know that JBoss includes RESTeasy since its seventh version, at least one provider uses jackson: org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jackson-provider.

This kind of error can happen when different versions of the same libraries are used to compile and to run a project but I don't find the culprit. I don't use jackson in my own code.

Does this bug come from JBoss? Is it fixed in a later version? Switching to WildFly isn't an option.

Comment: Have you excluded resteasy in jboss-deployment-structure.xml ?

Comment: No, I haven't put it into this file. I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I switched to Wildfly in the meantime for some projects (currently Wildfly 27). I can't confirm whether it's still reproducible with a more recent version of JBoss.